# How to update a DataTable data after updating the database?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have the following problem:

I have a view with a PrimeFaces components `<p:datatable />` and a `<p:contextMenu />` for that datatable. This contextMenu has a `actionListener` attribute to launch a method in the Managed Bean. This method only update the current state document's, I do this below a trigger.

When I click on the table's contextMenu, the field in the database (currenstate) is updated correctly, but, the new value of the current document's in the `<p:datatable />` is not updated.

How I can solve that problem?

This is my DAO Class:

```
@Stateless
public class TramitesDaoImp implements TramitesDao {
    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "tramites")
    EntityManager em;

// ... more methods 


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Tramite> findAllTramiteBy_EstadoTramite(boolean estadoTramite) {


        String consultaSql = "select t from Tramite t where t.estadoTramite = :paramEstado";

        Query query = em.createQuery( consultaSql );
        query.setParameter( "paramEstado", estadoTramite  ); 

        return query.getResultList();
    }



    @Override
public int passToNextLevel(int idTramite) {

    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery( "pasarTramiteNextLevel" );
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter( "idTramiteActual", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN );
    storedProcedure.setParameter( "idTramiteActual", idTramite );

    storedProcedure.execute();

    return 1;
}
```

This is my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TramitesBean implements Serializable{

@Inject
private TramitesService tramiteService;

//////// LISTS //////////////
private List< Tramite > listaTramiteObservados;
private List< Carrera > listaCarreras;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializar()
    {

// The method listarTodoTramiteBy_EstadoTramite( boolean ), calls this method : findAllTramiteBy_EstadoTramite( boolean ) to get a List
    this.listaTramiteObservados = tramiteService.listarTodoTramiteBy_EstadoTramite( true );
    this.listaCarreras = tramiteService.listarTodasCarreras();

}


//..... more methods
//.... getters and setters


    public void passToNextLevel()
    {
        int filasAfectadas = 0;

        // Pasamos el tramite seleccionado al siguiente nivel
        filasAfectadas = tramiteService.pasarSiguienteNivel( tramiteSeleccionado.getIdTramite() );

        if( filasAfectadas != 0 )
        {
            mostrarMensaje( "INFORMACION", "EL TRAMITE PASÓ AL SIGUIENTE NIVEL DE FORMA CORRECTA");
        }
        else
        {
            mostrarMensaje( "ATENCION", "HUBO UN ERROR AL PASAR EL TRAMITE AL SIGUIENTE NIVEL", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR );
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="mensajes" showDetail="true" />

    <p:dataTable id="tablaTramitesObs"
        value="#{tramitesBean.listaTramiteObservados}" var="obs"
        widgetVar="tablaObs" paginator="true" rows="10" stickyHeader="false"
        resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true" selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{tramitesBean.tramiteSeleccionado}"
        rowKey="#{obs.idTramite}"
        emptyMessage="NO SE ENCONTRARON RESULTADOS ">

            <f:facet name="filter" >
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF( 'tablaObs' ).filter()" style="width:190px">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="* TODOS *"
                        noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{tramitesBean.listaLugarActualTramite}"
                        var="lugarActual" itemLabel="#{lugarActual.descLugarActual}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{obs.lugaractualtramite.descLugarActual}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    <p:contextMenu for="tablaTramitesObs">
        <p:menuitem value="Pasar al Siguiente Nivel.." actionListener="#{tramitesBean.pasarAlSiguienteNivel() }" process="@form" update="@form" 
        immediate="false" />
    </p:contextMenu>
</h:form>
```

Comment: @Tiny, the reference will not be null. Right now in front of me I have used the `Inject` annotation to inject a `Stateless` bean into a `ViewScoped` `ManagedBean`. On a Facelets page I have a button that calls a method on the managed bean, which calls a method on the stateless bean, which prints a string. When I press the button, the string is printed, and there is no NullPointerException. This isn't much different than using the `EJB` annotation in a `ManagedBean`, which is legal, of course. I'm using Glassfish 4.1.

Comment: @DavidS : Yup! You are right. I deleted that misleading comment. (There is however, a general consensus - `@EJB` (and `@ManagedProperty` for JSF managed beans) in `@ManagedBean` (JSF) and `@Inject` in `@Named` (CDI) - Only local EJBs). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While `update="@form"` will "update" the table on the client-side, you may still need to update the `tramitesBean.listaTramiteObservados` collection on the server-side.

I'm not certain because you have not included the entire contents of the `TramitesBean` (thank you for keeping it simple), but I imagine your `listaTramiteObservados` is outdated. Can you get your `passToNextLevel` method to refresh the `listaTramiteObservados` from the database before returning? Then when the client-side `update` runs, it will read the new information.

Comment: is correct in that you posted to little detail in certain areas, but in otgers to much. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info on how to create a JSF MCVE

Comment: I think you meant to comment on Robert's question, @Kukeltje, not my answer.  I'm not sure he'll see this.

Comment: Thanks David, I going to do what you mentioned.

Comment: Great. If it works, @Robert, please mark my answer as correct. Otherwise maybe update your question, or post a new one and close this.

Comment: Hi to every onew again, I do what you suggest to me, but, the table is not update with the new value,

And to see the new value in the datatable (primefaces) **I need to _redeploy_ the application and the data table's is Update and showing the new value from the data base.**

Then the question is :

¿¿ How to update the `tramitesBean.listaTramiteObservados` collection on the server-side ???

Comment: @Robert, your `actionListener` method _could_ update the `listaTramiteObservados`. If you do not understand or that is not working,   I suggest you update your question with more details. But when you do, try to post the minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem as described by [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). The example should show `listaTramiteObservados` in `TramitesBean` so we can see how you are currently using it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidS , I post more code about my problem, Thanks for you help. ;D

Comment: @Robert, it looks like `listaTramiteObservados` is only populated once, in the `PostConstruct` method.  This list won't be automatically updated just because you made some database changes. You need to update the list in `pasarAlSiguienteNivel` by calling `listaTramiteObservados = tramiteService.findAllTramiteBy_EstadoTramite` again.

Comment: If this doesn't work I suggest you try to _greatly_ simplify your example, and preferably write the whole thing in English. I know that's not really "fair", but if you want help from an English-speaking person you'll get more results.